# Using webapps-deploy to deploy into a specifc folder (not just into wwwroot)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-webapps

Is it possible to use the [webapps-deploy](https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy) action to deploy into a specific path of the web app (and not just into `wwroot`)? For example deploying into a IIS virtual directory under `wwwroot/app`.

Current yaml GitHub action configuration, can't find a property here for setting a requested path on the web server.

```
- name: "Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials"
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: MyApp 
      publish-profile: ${{ secrets.SECRET_PROFILE  }}
      package: build
```

Image showing the Virtual Application (`wwwroot/app`) I'd like to deploy into

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With many times testing, I found it's not possible using Git Action. But you can consider using Visual Studio, importing publish profile.

**First**, set the virtual path in portal.
[image]
**Downloads the publish profile.** You will use the content of publish profile.

**Modify the profile.** Change `msdeploySite`'s value from `Your-Site` to `Your-Site\folder\subfolder`, such as msdeploySite="dorissub\app". Change `destinationAppUrl`'s value from `http://xxx.azurewebsites.net` to `http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/app`

**Publish from VS.**
[image]

**Check the sub folder.** it works.

[image]

---

Here is how I do using Git Action.

**Add secret.** Go to your GitHub repository settings and add a secret with the content of publish profile as the value, name it as `AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE`.

**Run workflow with this yaml file:**

```
name: .NET Core dorisxxx

on: [push]

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: dorisxxx    # set this to your application's name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '3.1.x'           # set this to the dot net version to use

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout the repo
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      
      # Setup .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} 
      
      # Run dotnet build and publish
      - name: dotnet build and publish
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build --configuration Release
          dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapp' 
          
      # Deploy to Azure Web apps
      - name: 'Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with: 
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }} # Replace with your app name
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }} # Define secret variable in repository settings as per action documentation
          package: '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapp'
```

But the project still published to wwwroot...

Maybe you should choose another way to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully deploy two web APIs to the same web service using virtual paths using GitHub actions. Here are the steps I took.

**Create virtual applications**
If you wanted your application to be named `test` then the `Virtual path` would be `/test` and the `Physical Path` value would be `site\wwwroot_test`. Having the physical path be `site\wwwroot\test` is also possible, however, this is the way I have gotten it to work. I also did not check either of the `Directory` or `Preload enabled` checkboxes.

**Modify the publish profile**
The `destinationAppUrl`'s value needs to add the path. See Doris Lv's answer.
**Add OutOfProcess AspNetCoreHostingModel**
For each of the web projects you want to host on the same web app, you need to add the following to each `.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Modify app service url**
Next since these applications are going to be in a different path than the root directory, you need to change the app service url to include the virtual path.

Example: instead of `www.https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/` it will now be `https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/test` if `/test` is the virtual path you created.

**Add deployment target step to GitHub action**
To deploy to the correct directory, you will need to add a step into your GitHub workflow. Here is a snippet of code from my workflow that sets the `DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable in the web service prior to the deploy composite action that I have setup.

Here is a snippet of the GitHub workflow:

```
# .github/workflows/cd.yml
jobs:
  # ... 
  target:
    needs: [set_environment, build, test, publish]
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment:
      name: ${{ needs.set_environment.outputs.my_env }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Run Composite Action Target
      uses: ./.github/actions/target
      with:
        Service-Principal: ${{ secrets.SPN }}
  deploy:
    needs: [set_environment, build, test, publish, target]
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment: 
      name: ${{ needs.set_environment.outputs.my_env }}
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: echo_environment
      run: |
        echo "The environment value is: 
${{needs.set_environment.outputs.my_env}}"
    - name: Run Composite Action Deploy
      uses: ./.github/actions/deploy
      with:
        Publish-Profile: ${{ secrets.TEST_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        Service-Principal: ${{ secrets.SPN }}
        Has-Api-Management-Service: true
```

Here is the composite action.

```
# .github/actions/target/action.yml
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ inputs.Service-Principal }}
    - name: Configure Azure Deployment Target
      run: az webapp config appsettings set --name ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }} --resource-group ${{ env.AZURE_APIM_RESOURCEGROUP }} --settings DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_TARGET }} --output none
      shell: pwsh
    - name: logout
      run: >
        az logout
      shell: pwsh
```

**Add concurrency to GitHub actions**
Since these deployment workflows are relying on the `DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` value being the correct `site\wwwroot_app` path, if two `cd.yml` GitHub actions run together, the builds may end up in the wrong directory. Therefore, to avoid this I added the same concurrency group to each of the cd workflows that deploy to the same web app.

```
name: Test Continuous Deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: TEST
    paths:
      - .github/**
      - TestDirectory/**
concurrency:
  group: webapp-deploy
```

**Some of the resources that helped me:**

- https://carldesouza.com/configuring-virtual-applications-with-azure-app-services-and-apim/
- https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy/issues/340
- [Deployed .Net Core 3.1 Web app on Azure shows error HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253744/deployed-net-core-3-1-web-app-on-azure-shows-error-http-error-500-35-ancm-mul)
- [Getting Error HTTP Error 500.34 - ANCM Mixed Hosting Models Not Supported after HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple Hosting models not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965795/getting-error-http-error-500-34-ancm-mixed-hosting-models-not-supported-after)